# maven-shade-plugin error: Cannot find setter, adder nor field in org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer for 'resource'

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, spring-boot, maven-shade-plugin

I was trying to run the Hello World example from Spring Boot. When I run 'mvn package' on the module I get the following error:-

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.1:shade (default) on project spring.boot: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven->shade->plugin:2.1:shade for parameter transformer: Cannot find setter, adder nor field in org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer for 'resource' -> [Help 1]

I haven't used any 'resource' attribute, but it seems to complain about this. Any idea what I am doing wrong here

Here is the pom for the module:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring.boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Main-Class>hello.SampleController</Main-Class>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first thing you could try is to not use the shade plugin (it's an inferior solution in general to the spring-boot plugin). The spring-boot plugin should be the one you find in all samples and guides in spring.io. With the starter-parent in use it's pretty trivial:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The parent has a configuration for `ManifestResourceTransformer` already, so I assume that's the problem. If you remove the `<executions/>` and set a property `start-class` it should work.

If you need to use shade for some reason and you want to take control of the configuration, then don't use the starter-parent as a parent (maybe just use it for [dependency management](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven-your-own-parent)).

Comment: Could you please tell the way how can I build executable jar not using shade plugin?

Comment: You need to be aware of some packaging differences here.  If you are using version >= 1.4.x of Spring Boot, the plugin changed to package the files under `BOOT-INF/classes`, _not_ at the root of the JAR file.  If you execute the JAR file in a way that expects the files to be at the root of the JAR file, execution will fail.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I use Command Prompt (cmd.exe) to package the project. When maven packs  the project, it will download all plugins, dependencies  (*Apache Maven Shade Plugin* in this case).
Cd to your project. Type:

```
mvn package
```

After packaging, it works. Hope it helps.