# Shaded Jar in Springboot

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, maven-2, maven-plugin

I'm trying to build shaded jar in spring boot application but having some issues. I don't know what i'm doing wrong here. I also read the following links but no luck
[maven-shade-plugin error: Cannot find setter, adder nor field in org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer for 'resource'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22999399/maven-shade-plugin-error-cannot-find-setter-adder-nor-field-in-org-apache-mave)

**here is my Pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>dashboard</groupId>
  <artifactId>dashboard</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>

  <dependency>
        <groupId>jira.widgets</groupId>
        <artifactId>jira-widgets</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency> 

         <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies> 


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>



    <!-- Additional lines to be added here... -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
                                <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <manifestEntries>

                                    <Main-Class>com.text.dashboard.hello.Application</Main-Class>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When i run mvn package then i got following exception on console

```
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building dashboard 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ dashboard ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\confiz\Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.3.RELEASE\dashboard\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ dashboard ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @ dashboard ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\confiz\Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.3.RELEASE\dashboard\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ dashboard ---
[INFO] Not copying test resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ dashboard ---
[INFO] Not compiling test sources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.15:test (default-test) @ dashboard ---
[INFO] Tests are skipped.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ dashboard ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\confiz\Documents\workspace-sts-3.7.3.RELEASE\dashboard\target\dashboard-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.1.5.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ dashboard ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-shade-plugin:2.3:shade (default) @ dashboard ---
[WARNING] Map in class org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer declares value type as: class java.util.jar.Attributes but saw: class java.lang.String at runtime
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.609 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-15T10:55:02+05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 22M/224M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.3:shade (default) on project dashboard: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.3:shade for parameter resource: Cannot find 'resource' in class org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

Scenario is : i have two spring boot projects and both have same type which executable jar. I'm adding other project in this project as dependency. That's why i'm building a jar which have all the dependencies

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you trying this? Spring boot already creates a jar with everything in it for you.... You are aware of the mixing of different spring boot versions (1.1.5 and 1.2.7) that is something you really should avoid!.

Comment: Scenario is : i have two spring boot projects and both have same type which executable jar. I'm adding other project in this project as dependency. That's why i'm building a jar which have all the dependencies

Comment: Then why have 2 separate projects in the first place? It won't work as it will only start a single application...

Comment: Why it won't work? Can you please explain it bit more

Comment: You have 2 executable jars, which one is going to execute? You have 2 executable classes,... How are you going to merge/manage the `application.properties`. Both classes have a very specific `MANIFEST.MF` for Spring Boot, how are you going to handle that, how are you merging the `lib` directory and making sure nothing breaks with that merge. I don't see why you need to do this.

Comment: That's why shaded plugin is in place. It'll copy the sources/resources thing in parent. The idea is that - its like dashboard application which have different widgets. Widgets like Jira, sonar etc. We are building a parent application which will have dependency of all the widgets (every widget is a separate project). So if i client says.i don't need JIRA widgets we'll simply remove the dependency of JIRA from dashboard pom and keep the Sonar dependency in pom.By the this way, code changes will be minimal

Answer (score 8):

I don't know why but it worked for me. Use just

```
<transformer    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
    <manifestEntries>
        <Main-Class>com.text.dashboard.hello.Application</Main-Class>
    </manifestEntries>
</transformer>
```

Instead of

```
 <transformers>
     <transformer    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
         <manifestEntries>
             <Main-Class>com.text.dashboard.hello.Application</Main-Class>
         </manifestEntries>
     </transformer>
</transformers>
```

Comment: scratch this: worked for me too, been wracking my brain over this one, thanks!
  'Worked' was an overstatement it just skipped editing a manifest, so seems like some issue in the parent pom with configuring shade plugin